# Troubleshooting wireless with OpenWrt?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, openwrt

Update: I'm an idiot and completely missed the big [DEBUGGING WIRELESS](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/debugging#wireless) on their FAQ. I'll either delete this or update when I actually have a better question.

A friend recently gave me an old router and it was working fine until recently. I'll admit, I'm the type of person that typically unplugs/resets the router when it goes down (you know, clear that DNS cache and all), but I have no clue where to start on trying to figure out whats going wrong.

Currently the 2.4 bgn connects (sometimes with authentication errors) and seems to throttle, as in preventing webpages from loading if you have a a music app running. The 5 an doesn't have a signal at all. Disabling the wireless, restarting OpenWrt, nothing works.

Nothing in the System Log looks out of the ordinary, so I'm kind of stuck on what exactly to do. Any suggestions?

---

dhcp file:

```
config dnsmasq
    option domainneeded '1'
    option boguspriv '1'
    option filterwin2k '0'
    option localise_queries '1'
    option rebind_protection '1'
    option rebind_localhost '1'
    option local '/lan/'
    option domain 'lan'
    option expandhosts '1'
    option nonegcache '0'
    option authoritative '1'
    option readethers '1'
    option leasefile '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
    option resolvfile '/tmp/resolv.conf.auto'
    option localservice '1'

config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '100'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv6 'server'
    option ra 'server'

config dhcp 'wan'
    option interface 'wan'
    option ignore '1'

config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
    option maindhcp '0'
    option leasefile '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
    option leasetrigger '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
```

network file

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd02:c489:8eef::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option type 'bridge'

config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 4'
```

wireless file:

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '11'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option txpower '17'
    option country 'US'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'EDITED'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'EDITED'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '36'
    option hwmode '11a'
    option path 'pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option txpower '13'
    option country 'US'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio1'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'EDITED'
    option ssid 'EDITED'
```